# Running a stored procedure via ASP file

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure as shown below (snippet) called `pGLTran_PartnerReimb_YTD`

```
exec @result =  master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @bcp

if @result = 0

   insert into [arp_Register].[dbo].[onestreamproclog] (Result) values ('1');

else

   insert into [arp_Register].[dbo].[onestreamproclog] (Result) values ('0');

GO
```

When I execute the procedure, it runs as expected and stored the result in the log table I created. But when the procedure is executed via an asp file, the procedure runs and loads the file to the server but doesn't insert the result into the table.

Comment: You need to give enough information that we can reproduce the issue.   There is nowhere near enough information here to try to help you right now.

Comment: Try adding a `commit` before `go`.

Comment: Broadly speaking, this implies a permissions issue on the insert into the `[arp_Register].[dbo].[onestreamproclog]` table. Does the login for the connection from the ASP page have insert permissions into that table, and connection permissions to that database?  Note that the permissions for the BCP are probably coded into the BCP command as a username and password for the imports (although the Windows login you use could have those permissions as well.)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @LaughingVergil, sounds like a permissions issue. ASP tends to run as an Anonymous user of  some type, which is going to have some very restrictive (rightfully so) permissions in SQL Server - unless it's logging in as a different user through the connection string.

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: set Conn2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set objCmd=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

Application("ConnectString")="ODBC;PROVIDER=MSDASQL;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=FGTandL;DATABASE=ARP_Register;UID=XX;PWD=YYYYY;"

Conn2.Open Application("ConnectString") 

objCmd.ActiveConnection = Conn2
objCmd.CommandText = "ARP_Register.dbo.pGLTran_PartnerReimb_YTD"
objCmd.Execute

strredirect="Pathname" 
response.Redirect(strredirect)

Comment: i didnt get any error message, the username has write access to the database, my alternative would be to add the insert statement in the asp file itsellf